# Invalid arguments for couchbase at laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, couchbase

I have a problem with laravel 5.4

I am using [mpociot/couchbase](https://github.com/ORT-Interactive-GmbH/laravel-couchbase). 
I am established the couchbase server and module of php couchbase and php/pcs

But I have the following error.

```
(1/2) ErrorException
Couchbase\Cluster::__construct() expects exactly 1 parameter, 3 given
```

config/database.php

```
  'couchbase' => [
        'driver'   => 'couchbase',
        'host'     => 'localhost',
        'port'     => '8091',
        'bucket'   => 'travel-sample',
        'username' => '',
        'n1ql_hosts' => [
            'http://'.env('DB_HOST', 'localhost').':8093'
        ]
    ],
```

Where do I mistake?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in mpociot's repo which is no longer supported.

The repo was moved to https://github.com/ORT-Interactive-GmbH/laravel-couchbase and we support this repo ;)

Comment: I was solve this problem and i used this package. The reason for my problem, couchbase version was too much. My first couchbase version 2.3.3, but this package supported 2.2.0 version.

Answer (score 2):

1. pcs is not necessary for couchbase extension anymore
2. The constructor in [src/Mpociot/Couchbase/Connection.php#L270](https://github.com/ORT-Interactive-GmbH/laravel-couchbase/blob/c5a19a8be56da1e15effcbe279c1ec95ab6d1e6b/src/Mpociot/Couchbase/Connection.php#L270) should be written as

   ```
   $cluster = new Cluster($config['host']);
   if (!empty($config['user']) && !empty($config['password'])) {
       $cluster->authenticateAs(strval($config['user']), strval($config['password']));
   }
   return $cluster;
   ```

   This is done in [ytake/Laravel-Couchbase](https://github.com/ytake/Laravel-Couchbase/blob/feature/laravel-55/src/Database/CouchbaseConnector.php#L39-L42) on the branch for Laravel 5.5.